# TypeScript - passing a class as an argument, and reflection

Tags: reflection, typescript, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am writing a generic unmarshaller. It converts graph DB data to generated TypeScript (1.8.7) model classes. The input is JSON. The output should be an instance of a model class.
*My ultimate goal is to create something like Hibernate OGM, only for Tinkerpop Frames and TypeScript, with REST endpoint in the middle.*

**What's the right way to pass a class as a parameter and reach it's static members?** I want to have something like this:

```
SomeModel some = <SomeModel> unmarshaller.fromJSON({/*Object from JSON*/}, SomeModel);
```

I've tried to write a method.
Not sure if I am heading in the right direction, feel free to suggest different approaches.

```
public fromJSON(input: Object, clazz: typeof FrameModel): FrameModel
{
    // This only demonstrates access to Framemodel's metadata 
    // about original Java model classes.
    clazz.graphPropertyMapping;
    clazz.graphRelationMapping;

    let result = {};
    ...
    return result;
}
...
```

But when I tried to execute this on Plunker, I got execution errors with unuseful stacktrace.

The model superclass looks like this:

```
/**
 * Things common to all Frames models on the Typescript side.
 */
export class FrameModel
{
    // Model metadata
    static discriminator: string;
    static graphPropertyMapping: { [key:string]:string; };
    static graphRelationMapping: { [key:string]:string; };

    // Each instance needs a vertex ID
    private vertexId: number;
    public getVertexId(): number {
        return this.vertexId;
    }
}
```

Sample model class:

```
import {TestPlanetModel} from './TestPlanetModel';
import {TestShipModel} from './TestShipModel';

export class TestGeneratorModel extends FrameModel
{
    static discriminator: string = 'TestGenerator';
    static graphPropertyMapping: { [key:string]:string; } = {
        bar: 'boo',
        name: 'name',
        rank: 'rank',
    };
    static graphRelationMapping: { [key:string]:string; } = {
        colonizes: 'colonizedPlanet',
        commands: 'ship',
    };

    boo: string;
    name: string;
    rank: string;

    public colonizedPlanet: TestPlanetModel[]; // edge label 'colonizedPlanet'

    public ship: TestShipModel; // edge label 'ship'

}
```

I haven't found much material on reflection and class handling in TypeScript.
I know how I would do this in Java.
I know how I would do this in JavaScript.
I understand that I might achieve similar results with decorators, but having fields or static fields seemed a bit simpler, for generated models.

Comment: Its conventional to call `class` `klass` :)

Answer (score 1):

You've maybe already noticed that class members cannot have `const` keyword. But you could go with `static` instead. Also member should be public if you want it to be accessible from outside world.

```
public static graphPropertyMapping: { [key:string]:string; } = {
    bar: 'boo',
    name: 'name',
    rank: 'rank',
};
```

As for creating result instance:

```
let result = new clazz();

//copy properties

return result;
```

Comment: Right, the example above was hand-written so contained these errors.

Comment: I actually wonder how TypeScript implements and limits 'static' - because in JavaScript, nothing is really static, it's bound to the Function. So technically, if you inherit from a Function, which is I guess how class inheritance is done in TS, you inherit the static field too? Therefore `MyClass.staticField` could technically also be accessed as `MySubclass.staticField`? Unless TS sticks with Java's notion of `static`...

Comment: Yes `MyClass.staticField` can also be accessed as `MySubclass.staticField`. You're right it is bound to the function (class definition)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then here's something to help you get started:

```
interface Model {}

interface ModelData {}

interface MyModelConstructor<M extends Model, D extends ModelData> {
    new(data: D): M;
    // static members
    graphPropertyMapping: any;
    graphRelationMapping: any;
}

class Unmarshaller {
    public fromJSON<T>(input: string | ModelData, ctor: MyModelConstructor<T, ModelData>): T {
        let data: ModelData = (typeof input === "string") ? JSON.parse(input) : input;

        let propertyMapping = ctor.graphPropertyMapping;
        let relationMapping = ctor.graphRelationMapping;

        // do whatever with the mappings

        return new ctor(input);
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Model%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ModelData%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyModelConstructor%3CM%20extends%20Model%2C%20D%20extends%20ModelData%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09new(data%3A%20D)%3A%20M%3B%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20static%20members%0D%0A%09graphPropertyMapping%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09graphRelationMapping%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Unmarshaller%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20fromJSON(input%3A%20string%20%7C%20ModelData%2C%20ctor%3A%20MyModelConstructor%3CT%2C%20ModelData%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09let%20data%3A%20ModelData%20%3D%20(typeof%20input%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%3F%20JSON.parse(input)%20%3A%20input%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09let%20propertyMapping%20%3D%20ctor.graphPropertyMapping%3B%0D%0A%09%09let%20relationMapping%20%3D%20ctor.graphRelationMapping%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20do%20whatever%20with%20the%20mappings%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20ctor(input)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

I don't know how your models look like, so I hope this is close enough.

Comment: This looks sensible. Could you please add some link to the rationale behind the need for an interface? I  mean, in Java, there's no need for an interface to inspect the class metadata and annotations. Is this an "official" way or leveraging of some side effect? Thanks

Comment: In typescript [interfaces have many roles](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), and you don't have to use them, but it makes sense. In my example I did not use metadata nor annotations, the only thing here is the interface that represents a reference to a class (as opposed to a reference to an instance): `MyModelConstructor`.  If you'll be more specific about what you want to know I'll modify my answer to accommodate that.

Comment: I understood your example a bit more. Looks like you are suggesting to have a constructor class for each model. I.e. each model would have respective constructor class. Since I generate the models, I would prefer if there was just a single service class that would be able to construct the model out of the JSON data and the metadata in the model class. I think I'll improve my question's code.

Comment: You don't need to have different ctor classes, you can have just one, it's up to you. Also, you don't need to have the generics parts that I included, it's just easier in my opinion and removes the need to cast later on. But as you don't include how it is that you create instances of these models, it's hard for me to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: I don't create the instances yet. That's one of things that I am yet to figure out. My initial idea is to create an `Object` with respective properties needed by the particular model, and then cast it.

Comment: In your example, 1) how would i call `fromJSON`, and 2) how would the model look like? I wonder how do I override the `static` parts.

Comment: You cannot cast `Object` to another class, it doesn't work that way, just like you can't cast java `Object` to a different class. You use it like: `unmarshaller.fromJson(JSON_STRING, MyModelClass)`. I would love to help you, but I still haven't managed to figure out what you're trying to do. What's up with all of those static data? why is that needed? How would you do what you want to do with java for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118561/discussion-between-ondra-zizka-and-nitzan-tomer).

Comment: My ultimate goal is to create something like Hibernate OGM, only for Tinkerpop Frames and TypeScript, with REST endpoint in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released an enhanced version of the TypeScript compiler that allows exactly what you are expecting: read all (static or not) fields metadata from a class. For example you can write:

```
interface MyInterface {
    active:boolean;
    description: string;
}

class MyClass {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    myComplexField: MyInterface;
}

function printMembers(clazz: Class) {
    let fields = clazz.members.filter(m => m.type.kind !== 'function'); //exclude methods.
    for(let field of fields) {
        let typeName = field.type.kind;
        if(typeName === 'class' || typeName === 'interface') {
            typeName = (<Class | Interface>field.type).name;
        }
        console.log(`Field ${field.name} of ${clazz.name} has type: ${typeName}`);
    }
}

printMembers(MyClass.getClass());
```

this is the output:

```
$ node main.js
Field id of MyClass has type: number
Field name of MyClass has type: string
Field myComplexField of MyClass has type: MyInterface
```

Of course, if you change the `members` property access of clazz to `statics` you will retrieve all static members. These information can be accessed at coding time too, so you can use autocompletion. 
You can do the same with Interfaces metadata. Simply write `MyInterface` for example, and access its members.
You can find the project [here](https://github.com/pcan/reflec-ts).

Comment: Nice avatar @pcan